# What's implicit method call and explicit method call?

Tags: python, terminology

I read about those terms in my python text book. I can't figure out the meaning by looking up the literal meaning of them. Could someone explain that to me or provide me some reference?

--update the context of the term

```
i) (­42).__abs__() # Need parentheses to avoid confusing ... # ... method call '.' with decimal point
j) (42).__mul__(2) # Even multiplication is a method call
k) name.swapcase()
l) name.title().swapcase() # name.title() is an object so ... m) name.upper().find('TOM') # ... we can “cascade” method calls.
```

> Hopefully you now realise that most of the operations you've done so
> far in this course have actually been provided by implicitly calling
> methods of the objects (data items) that you've been working with.
> Indeed, all operators ('+', '*' etc) are just syntactic shortcuts for
> method calls, but only some of the built-in functions correspond to
> methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know the context of these terminologies in your book but I found [implicit-vs-explicit-programming](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/74798-implicit-vs-explicit-programming/). It first talked about `explicit programming` and `implicit programming` then `implicit method call` and `explicit member call`. Not sure whether it can help. Maybe you can give us more details.

**EDIT**:

I suppose what it means is that when you use `3+2` or `3*2` it seems you you don't explicitly call any method but in fact you called because the way they are implemented is calling the `(3).__add__(2)` or `(3).__mul__(2)`. So you are calling these methods implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link, I still waiting for some code example BTW I've updated the context of the term in my text book

Answer (score 4):

implicit method call means the particular method will be called by itself(like by the JVM in java) and explicit method call means the method will be called by the user.

Comment: I think a default constructor call when allocating memory for an object can be considered as an implicit method call (even constructor is a special method). And calling a user defined method can be considered as an explicit method call

Comment: And i can give another example when we use System.out.println() in java and try to print an integer ,System.out.println() automatically calls toString() to convert the particular interger value to string and later it prints it

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, Python invokes certain methods implicitly as a result of certain operators (like '+', '-', '*', '.', '//', (), del, etc.) or builtin functions (like repr, str, divmod, pow, etc.) being used in an expression. The methods called thus are term "magic methods" or "dunder" as most of them are named with a `__` prefix and suffix.

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html for more details.

These methods can be called explicitly as well. For example, as in your question:

```
abs(42)
```

can be [called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66287670/6862601) as:

```
(42).__abs__()
```

or

```
42.0.__abs__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit calling is function calling which is made by the compiler automatically without user's interference, whereas explicit calling is made by the user using specific type of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows for Implicit and Explicit function calls.

Example:

```
public class Junk
{
  private int a = 1;
  public String toString () { return (a); }
}

void main (String [] args)
{
  Junk j = new Junk (); // implicit call to Junk's default constructor 
  System.out.println (j); // implicit call to j.toString();
  System.out.println (j.toString()); // explicit call to j.toString();
}
```