# Why do I need to enclose a literal in parentheses while invoking a method?

Tags: python, syntax

## Without ()

```
42.__abs__()
  File "<ipython-input-43-9690433aefe5>", line 1
    42.__abs__()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## With ()

```
(42).__abs__()
42
```

What is the reason for `()` being necessary here?

Comment: It's **not** necessary. You could also do `42 .__abs__()`.

Comment: @MarkM `-42`. (And now let me go test it... :-)

Comment: `-42 .__abs__()` does not return absolute value, it just returns `-42`, whereas `(-42).__abs__()` spits out `42`. Whereas if both ways are alternatives why value comes out to be different?

Comment: The real question is, why would you write code that way? The code you want to run is `abs(42)`. `42.` is apparently parsed as a floating point number (see the syntax highlighting as well), and then "adding" a literal `__abs__` to that is meaningless. Another question is why you would need to call `abs()` on an integer literal at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`42.` will be interpreted by the parser as a float `42.0`. Ergo the `.` is not recognized as the connector between an instance and one of its methods. Python rightfully complains that there is some variable name directly after a float, since that is invalid syntax.